# Превратить данные в словарь Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

В процессе парсинга столкнулся вот с такими данными:

```
{'OPTIONS': {'table': {'CODE': 'table', 'SORT': '30', 'TITLE': 'Выберите стол', 'TITLE2': 'Без стола', 'ITEMS': {'0': {'ID': '310079', '~ID': '310079', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол укороченный 80*54 см для машины A-8700', '~NAME': 'Стол укороченный 80*54 см для машины A-8700', 'XML_ID': '104614/0', '~XML_ID': '104614/0', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a8e/225_175_1/a8e733dac9fb5c89722140ed5d890dbc.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '79772', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005679', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005679', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '30', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '30', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174690', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174690', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '104614/0', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '104614/0', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 12, 'QUANTITY_R': 1, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '304603', 'PRODUCT_ID': '310079', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '1': {'ID': '310101', '~ID': '310101', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', '~NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', 'XML_ID': '58508/0', '~XML_ID': '58508/0', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/8a9/225_175_1/8a9291bd8e43d1e7659b947a73cf3725.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '121976', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 2, 'QUANTITY_R': 0, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '304604', 'PRODUCT_ID': '310101', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '3': {'ID': '538652', '~ID': '538652', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол Aurora фирменный с вырезом под ремень для моделей А-8700/A-0302/A-0818', '~NAME': 'Стол Aurora фирменный с вырезом под ремень для моделей А-8700/A-0302/A-0818', 'XML_ID': '276376', '~XML_ID': '276376', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': None, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': None, 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '16848683', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '16848683', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': '02/10/2021', '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': '02/10/2021', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': '21132669', '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': '21132669', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '113', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '113', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21186562', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21186562', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818', '~CODE': 'stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '276376', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '276376', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 651, 'QUANTITY_R': 115, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '488624', 'PRODUCT_ID': '538652', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '2': {'ID': '400887', '~ID': '400887', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол EURO1 для Juki DDL-8100/8700, DLN-5410, DU-1181', '~NAME': 'Стол EURO1 для Juki DDL-8100/8700, DLN-5410, DU-1181', 'XML_ID': '281969', '~XML_ID': '281969', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/1cc/225_175_1/1cca5575d35210730f989c736263bf97.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '124406', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '19751439', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '19751439', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '57', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '57', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174884', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174884', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '281969', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '281969', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 6, 'QUANTITY_R': 0, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '305397', 'PRODUCT_ID': '400887', 'PRICE': '127.43', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 9400, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '9 400 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 9400, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '9 400 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 127.43, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$127.43', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}}}}, 'STATUS': 'OK'}
```

Перебрал несколько решений, но во всех получал ошибки (что-то про кавычки не те, ошибочные атрибуты и т.п.). Попытки исправить к успехам не привели.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше распарсить с примером?
PS И еще вопрос: этот код - JSON?

Comment: да. Похоже на джейсон. Как парсить джейсон написано с примерами на 100500 сайтах

Comment: Попробуй заменить ковычки на двойные. Тогда возможно проблема уйдёт. JSON требует именно двойные.

Comment: словарь как словарь... data = ваши данные data.keys() dict_keys(['OPTIONS', 'STATUS']) вы его распарсить хотите или отправить куда-то?

Comment: Это и так словарь.. всеже начальная версия была правильная. например pprint(dic["OPTIONS"]["table"]["ITEMS"]["0"]["AVAILABLE_CLASS"])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {'OPTIONS': {'table': {'CODE': 'table', 'SORT': '30', 'TITLE': 'Выберите стол', 'TITLE2': 'Без стола', 'ITEMS': {'0': {'ID': '310079', '~ID': '310079', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол укороченный 80*54 см для машины A-8700', '~NAME': 'Стол укороченный 80*54 см для машины A-8700', 'XML_ID': '104614/0', '~XML_ID': '104614/0', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a8e/225_175_1/a8e733dac9fb5c89722140ed5d890dbc.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '79772', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005679', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005679', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '30', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '30', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174690', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174690', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-ukorochennyy-80-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '104614/0', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '104614/0', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 12, 'QUANTITY_R': 1, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '304603', 'PRODUCT_ID': '310079', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '1': {'ID': '310101', '~ID': '310101', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', '~NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', 'XML_ID': '58508/0', '~XML_ID': '58508/0', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/8a9/225_175_1/8a9291bd8e43d1e7659b947a73cf3725.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '121976', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 2, 'QUANTITY_R': 0, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '304604', 'PRODUCT_ID': '310101', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '3': {'ID': '538652', '~ID': '538652', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол Aurora фирменный с вырезом под ремень для моделей А-8700/A-0302/A-0818', '~NAME': 'Стол Aurora фирменный с вырезом под ремень для моделей А-8700/A-0302/A-0818', 'XML_ID': '276376', '~XML_ID': '276376', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': None, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': None, 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '16848683', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '16848683', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': '02/10/2021', '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': '02/10/2021', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': '21132669', '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': '21132669', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '113', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '113', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21186562', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21186562', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818', '~CODE': 'stol-aurora-a-8700-a-0302-a-0818', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '276376', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '276376', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 651, 'QUANTITY_R': 115, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '488624', 'PRODUCT_ID': '538652', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}, '2': {'ID': '400887', '~ID': '400887', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол EURO1 для Juki DDL-8100/8700, DLN-5410, DU-1181', '~NAME': 'Стол EURO1 для Juki DDL-8100/8700, DLN-5410, DU-1181', 'XML_ID': '281969', '~XML_ID': '281969', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/1cc/225_175_1/1cca5575d35210730f989c736263bf97.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '124406', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '19751439', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '19751439', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '57', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '57', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174884', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '21174884', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-euro1-dlya-juki-ddl-8100-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '281969', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '281969', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 6, 'QUANTITY_R': 0, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '305397', 'PRODUCT_ID': '400887', 'PRICE': '127.43', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 9400, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '9 400 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 9400, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '9 400 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 127.43, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$127.43', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}}}}, 'STATUS': 'OK'}
```

тут готовый словарь:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(data, depth=4)
```

выведет:

```
{'OPTIONS': {'table': {'CODE': 'table',
                       'ITEMS': {'0': {...},
                                 '1': {...},
                                 '2': {...},
                                 '3': {...}},
                       'SORT': '30',
                       'TITLE': 'Выберите стол',
                       'TITLE2': 'Без стола'}},
 'STATUS': 'OK'}
```

вытащить содержимое по ключам:

```
>>> data['OPTIONS']['table']['ITEMS']['1']
{'ID': '310101', '~ID': '310101', 'IBLOCK_ID': '2', '~IBLOCK_ID': '2', 'NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', '~NAME': 'Стол стандартный 120*54 см для машины A-8700', 'XML_ID': '58508/0', '~XML_ID': '58508/0', 'DETAIL_PICTURE': {'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'size': None, 'SRC': '/upload/resize_cache/iblock/8a9/225_175_1/8a9291bd8e43d1e7659b947a73cf3725.jpg'}, '~DETAIL_PICTURE': '121976', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', '~DETAIL_PAGE_URL': '/catalog/stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700/', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE': 'стол', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_ENUM_ID': '135', 'PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', '~PROPERTY_TYPE_COMPLECT_VALUE_ID': '17005747', 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE': None, 'PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, '~PROPERTY_PRICE_TRANSIT_VALUE_ID': None, 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE': '0', 'PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', '~PROPERTY_DIOH_VALUE_ID': '18461402', 'LANG_DIR': '/', '~LANG_DIR': '/', 'CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', '~CODE': 'stol-standartnyy-120-54-sm-dlya-mashiny-a-8700', 'EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', '~EXTERNAL_ID': '58508/0', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', '~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID': '2604', 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', '~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'catalog', 'IBLOCK_CODE': '', '~IBLOCK_CODE': '', 'IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', '~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID': '', 'LID': 's1', '~LID': 's1', 'QUANTITY': 2, 'QUANTITY_R': 0, 'PRICES': {'0': {'ID': '304604', 'PRODUCT_ID': '310101', 'PRICE': '62.00', 'CURRENCY': 'USD', 'CATALOG_GROUP_ID': '1'}}, 'AVAILABLE': 1, 'AVAILABLE_CLASS': 'in_stock', 'AVAILABLE_TITLE': 'в наличии', 'AVAILABLE_DIOH': '', 'PRICE_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 4574, 'PRICE_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '4 574 Р', 'PRICE_USD_DISCOUNT_VALUE': 62, 'PRICE_USD_PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE': '$62', 'BONUS_VALUE': None, 'BONUS_FORMATED': ''}
```